# Missing frameworks after upgrading to Xcode 3.2

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I upgraded to Xcode 3.2 and now can't seem to add a number of frameworks, specifically the media player.  A number of frameworks do not show up on the "Add Existing Frameworks Sheet".

Per another question I tried setting the "Framework Search Path" to

```
$(SDKROOT)/Library/System/Frameworks
```

but that didn't seem to make any difference.  The UIKit.framework that is included by default when I create a new project is in

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
```

which I would expect.  If I navigate to that directory I see the MediaPlayer.framework and can drag and drop it into my project successfully, but can only build and debug for a device-no suprise there, but not ideal.

I uninstalled the dev tools with

```
mode=all
```

and reinstalled Xcode, but still no relief.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you re-install the iPhone SDK?

Comment: Seconded. When you install Xcode 3.2, you'll probably need to install the iPhone SDK over top of it to get all the iPhone stuff. When I upgraded to Snow Kitty, I had to do the same thing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your project was probably configured to use an older SDK that's not included in the Xcode 3.2 + iPhone SDK package.  Go to your target's Get Info panel, Build settings, and set the Base SDK to an SDK that's actually installed.

If you want your app to run on older iPhone OSes, set the iPhone Deployment Target build setting to the earliest OS you want to run on.

Comment: I just answered this question and I didn't really ready your answer, which is the same as mine (more or less), so I marked you up +1. (^_^)

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue when upgrading to 3.1.2.  One thing you will want to do is open your Xcode Project, right-click on the project and Get Info...  Then change the Base SDK for All Configurations to (the minimum of) 2.2.1.

When I did this it re-linked all of my RED (missing) Frameworks.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is over a year old, but I just had a similar problem and solved it by looking for the missing framework in the trash and putting it back.

I must've deleted it by accident!

Comment: This solved my problem, perhaps the frameworks got deleted when I was removing "test" projects or something.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution 1: Clean Your Project
Build > Clean All Target

Possible Solution 2: Make Sure Your Device is in Correct Firmware

To debug, read console log.

Hope it helps.