# Cannot find UIKit.framework

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, uikit, xcode6

I am currently running Xcode 6 beta 2, and I can't find the UIKit.framework.
I've looked in System/Library/Frameworks as suggested in [Apple's reference page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uikit_framework/_index.html)

All the other frameworks are there, except UIKit.

Note: I have no issues importing the UIKit framework

Comment: by mistake it have been deleted , check in trash...

Comment: I'm 100% sure I didn't delete it. I checked Trash just to be sure, no luck.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533272/missing-frameworks-after-upgrading-to-xcode-3-2

Comment: My problem isnt within Xcode, I just can't understand why I can't find the file...

Comment: Try re-installing the XCode . and even it is in beta as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UIKit.framework is here

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks`

Comment: Xcode 13 beta location: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework

Answer (score 13):

In the newer Xcode versions the iPhoneOS frameworks do no longer include a binary, but include a [tbd file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32115656/3562415). You can find simulator binaries at this path:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks

Answer (score 11):

New location:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks`

Answer (score 5):

iOS 14, Xcode 12 path I've found here

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
```

Answer (score 3):

The path to UIKitCore (which actually contains everything in UIKit) in Xcode 12 is:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you already find it out, but just for the record: the UIKit.framework is available only on iOS platform. The path **/System/Library/Frameworks/** contains the frameworks that your Mac OS X has installed (not your Xcode).

The iOS frameworks that are used in iOS projects, at least when using Xcode, is the following:

> /Applications/Xcode6-Beta4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

The **Xcode6-Beta4.app** part of the path is the app name of your Xcode in your Applications folder, that can be somewhat different if you have another version installed. Also, the **iPhoneOS8.0.sdk** can be different if you're using other SDK version (iOS 7.0, for example).

EDIT: If the UIKit.framework is there, then you probably changed some configuration in your Xcode. The easier way to fix it is probably by deleting it and reinstalling.

Comment: But there is no exec file inside the framework directory, why?

Answer (score 2):

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore

Answer (score 2):

Updated for Xcode 11.3:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework`

Answer (score 0):

You can find UIKit Mach-O file in both Mac(Xcode installed) and iOS:

1. In mac, the path of UIKit is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore`(for Xcode 14.2)
2. In iOS, there is a image file: `/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/dyld_shared_cache_X`, you can use [dsc_extrator](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/dyld/blob/main/other-tools/dsc_extractor.cpp) to extract all contents of this image file into a directory(such as `arm64`). Then the UIKit is located in `arm64/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore`