# libstdc++.6.0.0.tbd or .dylib

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

So folks I'm developing an app and an SDK I use require adding `libstdc++.6.0.0.dylib`, and there's no .dylib when I search it and a .tbd shows up instead.
I just googled the difference between the two and wanna know if it's okay that I add `.tbd` into my project instead of `.dylib`?

Comment: yes .. its ok ..check this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450690/why-xcode-7-shows-tbd-instead-of-dylib

Comment: Thanks El Capitain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add the library, rather than hunt though the list, just press "Add Other" then manually navigate to /usr/lib or just press "CMD + Shift + G" then type in "/usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib"

Comment: `file /usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib` says that library supports `x86_64` and `i386` architectures, so will this work on a device or only on the simulator?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using xcode 11, you need to check the path to copy the library libstdc++. ~~/usr/lib path has changed.

simulator
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/`

ios
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib/`

Comment: I updated my XCode and faced a similar issue while running my app on the simulator. After using the correct path for the simulator and copying all related dylib, I solved the issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to solve the problem, you can try to manually copy the file to lib.

1.`iPhoneOS` and `iPhoneSimulator` file

copy the original file: libstdc++.6.0.9.tbd and libstdc++.6.tbd and libstdc++.tbd to :

- /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib/
- /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/

2.`iOS.simruntime` file

copy the original file: libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib and libstdc++.6.dylib and libstdc++.dylib to:

- /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib

Answer (score 1):

Here is a temporary solution.

1. Download libstdc++. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/luapower/libstdcxx/master/bin/linux64/libstdc%2B%2B.a
2. Unzip, copy `/libstdcxx-master/bin/linux64/libstdc++.a` to Xcode Frameworks, renamed `libstdc++.6.0.9.a`, make sure the Link Binary With Libraries also add in this file.
3. Run again and pass the compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Add this "libstdc++.6.dylib". at this below path

For simulator
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/