# library not found for -lstdc++.6 when using IBM Mobile First 8 with Xcode 10

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

It seems that the latest version IBM's Mobile First (8.0.2018081607) is not compatible with the latest version of Xcode (10.0, 10A255). When I try to build my app for iOS using this setup I get the following error:

Native linking error: library not found for -lstdc++.6   MT5209

Is there a way tell the linker to use libc++ instead of lstdc++ for ibm's dependency libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the dependency in your Xcode project. See https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2018/07/23/mfp-support-for-ios12/#known-issues for instructions.

Comment: Hi Srik, your link was very useful on finding the solution, I forgot to mention that my project is actually a Xamarin Visual Studio project, so I don't have an XCode project and can't remove that reference. However I was able to fix it by downloading Xcode 9.4 from the apple developer portal and manually copying all of the *libstdc* libraries onto the XCode 10's install folder, see this post for reference and exact details on how to do it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694822/xcode-10-ios-12-does-not-contain-libstdc6-0-9/50734510#50734510

Comment: I went ahead and accepted your comment as answer since it was very helpful on finding the solution. Thanks!

Comment: PLease contact IBM for fix for Xamarin although it will be available on NuGet shortly