# Xcode 11.1: iostream' file not found

Tags: c++, xcode, iostream, clang++, macos-catalina

I just updated my **MacBook Pro** to **macOS Catalina 10.15**, and tried to compile and run a **C++ command line program**, but I had a problem which didn’t exist on previous versions;

This is simply the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and outputs the expected, but still the Xcode says:

```
fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
```

I tried changing the **Build Settings/C++ Standard Library** to **libstdc++**, but a warning says:

```
warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-stdlib=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead
```

And the same iostream error still exists.

Comment: libstdc++ is deprecated and is not available in xcode 11

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 10 (iOS 12) does not contain libstdc++6.0.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694822/xcode-10-ios-12-does-not-contain-libstdc6-0-9)

Comment: Have you updated XCode?

Comment: Alan Britles thanks for your time, how do I deal with this problem? No more C++ on XCode?

Comment: molbdnilo yes, latest version.

Comment: So, I restarted my laptop and everything seems to be fine right now, thanks for those who tried to help.

Comment: @AlanBirtles if duplicate, how to use vector in Mac?

Answer (score 3):

I'm compiling from the command line, and none of the answers listed here (or elsewhere) worked for me.

What does seem to work (so far) is to add the following to `.profile` or whatever script your terminal uses to start up: (zsh, csh, bash, etc.)

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include
```

You will probably have to change `MacOSX10.15.sdk` whenever you upgrade your operating system.

`C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` are options for the clang toolchain rather than MacOS environment, so hopefully this solution will work long-term, unlike `xcode-select --install` (which won't fix the include directories on an upgrade) or `ln -s ... /usr/include` (which is now forbidden by System Integrity Protection).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and used the following youtube video to fix it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrPm7tWC-BI&feature=youtu.be

or you can follow this path. Make sure to include the quotation marks

Project - Build Settings - Search Paths - Headers Search Paths, and add the following path:
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/"

Answer (score 0):

`libstdc++` is not OK for Xcode Build & Compile time,

`libstdc++` is OK for iPhone Run Time

---

From answer recommended by @Alan Birtles

> `libstdc++` Support was removed from the iOS 12.0 Simulator runtime, but
>   it remains in the iOS 12.0 (device) runtime for binary compatibility
>   with shipping apps.

---

I encountered this when declaration in `.hpp` file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

---

OK with

```
#ifdef __cplusplus

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// usage code
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a fresh Catalina install with Xcode. I copied and pasted your code into "test.cpp" and then ran:

clang++ test.cpp

in the same directory as the "test.cpp" file from Terminal. The result was an "a.out" file which when run:

./a.out

output the required "Hello, World!" result. Hopefully that is of some use (as a point of reference).

Comment: The OP already said that older versions worked. Not sure how this is helpful.

Comment: Tried the same on a new Catalina install, works fine.