# Google analytics manual install libz.dylib

Tags: ios, google-analytics, xcode8

I'm trying to install Google Analytics Service SDK to Xcode project manually.

The google doc says I need to add `libz.dylib` to linked libraries.  When I tap plus button on Linked Frameworks and Libraries section in general tab of a target and typed `libz` in search box, there aren't any result match exactly `libz.dylib`. I get followings instead.

- libz.1.1.3.tbd
- libz.1.2.5.tbd
- libz.1.2.8.tbd
- libz.1.tbd
- libz.tbd

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sdk-download#download_sdk

What should I add (or maybe add nothing) instead?

I use Xcode 8.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

You can add all `.tbd` files of `libz` instead of `.dylb`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32115656/7456236) answer, it may help you.

Comment: It is true, you can use .tbd files.