# Missing framework is red and project still builds

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, ld, libstdc++

I have a missing framework shown in red in a pod project.  The project still builds for running when selecting "Generic iOS Device".  However, if I remove the red framework then the project stops building and Xcode reports "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:" and a big list of symbols not being found by the linker.  This is the library which I understand from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694822/xcode-10-ios-12-does-not-contain-libstdc6-0-9) has been deprecated and is no longer included in Xcode as of Xcode 10.

[image]

I'm currently downloading Xcode 9.4.1 so that I can get the old libraries, but I'm unclear why I can even build successfully when this library is red.  Again if I remove it it won't build. As a related aside, the project is already set to use libc++ rather than libstdc++.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to delete the libstdc++.tbd, then under Xcode's general tab, Linked Frameworks and Libraries, add libc++.tbd.  Also, under the Build Settings tab, C++ Standard Library should be set as libc++.  In my project the C++ Standard Library was already set to libc++.

Since as of Xcode 10 libstdc++.tbd is not available it was shown in red. The calls to the standard library I think are now linked via libc++.tbd.

This other SO posts discusses the [tbd files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450690/why-xcode-7-shows-tbd-instead-of-dylib)